# Are Dwight's "What is my perfect crime?" lines in S05E08 - "Frame Toby" a reference to something?

Tags: dialogue, reference, the-office

Are Dwight's "*What is my perfect crime?*" lines in Season 5, Episode 8 titled "Frame Toby", a reference to something? What is being referenced to?

The lines:

> **Dwight:** What is my perfect crime? I break into Tiffany's at midnight. Do I go for the vault? No, I go for the chandelier. It's priceless. As I'm taking it down, a woman catches me. She tells me to stop. It's her father's business. She's Tiffany. I say no. We make love all night. In the morning, the cops come and I escape in one of their uniforms. I tell her to meet me in Mexico, but I go to Canada. I don't trust her. Besides, I like the cold. Thirty years later, I get a postcard. I have a son and he's the chief of police. This is where the story gets interesting. I tell Tiffany to meet me in Paris by the Trocadero. She's been waiting for me all these years. She's never taken another lover. I don't care. I don't show up. I go to Berlin. That's where I stashed the chandelier.

<sup>Source: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1248752/quotes?item=qt0502430</sup>

Comment: I don't think any of Dwight's fantasies are in reference to anything based in reality.

Comment: I am pretty sure the joke is that Dwight's perfect crime is so thoroughly thought out.

Comment: @JackBNimble: I know this is an ancient post now, but you should add that comment as an answer. I did a pretty extensive search online and there's absolutely nothing there. It's just Dwight being Dwight, as you correctly say.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**It appears the crime is his own creation.**

Extensive searching hasn't unearthed *any* movies that are being referenced here and it doesn't appear in any cast interviews. It seems far more likely that the crime is just another example of the *bizarre nature* of Dwight, which is evident throughout the entire series.